# wpf xceed Rich Text Box FormatBar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I keep getting this error when I try to use the wpf `xceed` `RichTextBox` `FormatBar`:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Initialization of
>   'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBoxFormatBar' threw an exception. --->
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException: Initialization of
>   'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core.VersionResourceDictionary' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I remove the format bar from my **xaml** file my code runs fine so I know the **xceed** library is loaded. For some reason the just the format bar is not working. Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Does the lib's target framework higher than your app?

Comment: could offer more details, like what version of .net u using and the structure of your solution ?

Comment: I'm making a class library that works as a program extension for Autodesk Revit. My target framework is .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but when I changed back to version 2.0 (from 2.5) of the Xceed toolbox DLL this problem went away.